# Matter.js i need always same movement ( on any canvas size)

Tags: matter.js

I need help. I have a player and I want jump the player in same diametric order. I wanted to fix this with getHeight with return ( innerHeight/100 * per ), but there's no improvement. Even worse, if the canvas size becomes bigger the player doesn't jump as high and if the window becomes smaller the player jumps higher! I dont want to callibrate in hard code way. I need responsive function!

"leave a comment before vote negative"

```
r.player.force = {
 x: 0,
 y: -(getHeight(0.03)),
};
Matter.Body.applyForce(r.player, { x: r.player.position.x, y: r.player.position.y }, r.player.force);

public getHeight(percente: number): number {    
 return this.reperH() / 100 * percente;    
}

this.reperH = function () {

 if ((window as any).innerHeight > (window as any).innerWidth / this.aspectRatio) {
  return (window as any).innerWidth / this.aspectRatio;
    } else {
      return (window as any).innerHeight;
    }

 };
```

Full source : link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure that matter.js already have diametric scale with simple number inputs.

When i remove all getHeight and getWidth and put numbers everything start works fine again.

It is my solution for any platform to get percent always no matter for screen size.
 My opinion : Matter.js looks like good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a single function to do everything, but you can multiply the force by `window.innerHeight` or `window.innerWidth`:

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var vw = windowWidth/100;
var vh = windowHeight/100;
var jumpForce = vh*-5;
var pushX = vw*0.1;
```

After that, you just apply `jumpForce` to the player when they jump and `pushX` to the player when they move (You will have to multiply it by -1 when the player is moving to the left). If you want it to look even more consistent, you can have `jumpForce` use `vw` instead of `vh` and make sure all of the objects created in the game use `vw` for positioning and scaling.

Whether you do use only `vw` or not, you will have to convert all your pixel values into `vw` or `vh` (depending on whether you're changing the x or y of the object), so it looks like this:

```
var object = Bodies.rectangle(vw*60, vw*40, vw*8, vw*5);
```